# Importing large Excel file to Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to import an Excel (`.xlsx`) file into the Spyder IDE. Everything works fine when I import small files, using `openpyxl`, but for this particular file (around 30MB and 800k rows) my system crashes.

Following is the part of code that imports:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook 
wb = load_workbook(filename=path + 'cleaned_noTC_s_PERNO_Date.xlsx', data_only=True)
```

Can anyone please let me know what is wrong with this method and what else can I use to import the stated file?

Comment: any way you can share the excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the excellent pandas library, it has very robust excel reading functionality and is pretty good with memory in my experience:

See [here](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/io.html#reading-excel-files):

```
import pandas as pd
xl = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're running out of memory. If you don't need to edit the file then you can use `read_only` mode, otherwise you'll need more memory.